# TYPO3 Ext. Custom Routes: Reverse Resolution not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I am struggling with the URL generation of TYPO3 in my own extension.

**Site Config:**

```
routeEnhancers:
  JobsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages: [11]
    extension: Company
    plugin: Jobs
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{job_title}', _controller: 'Jobs::job', _arguments: {'job_title': 'id'} }
    defaultController: 'Jobs::job'
    requirements:
      job_title: '[0-9]{1..6}'
    aspects:
      job_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_company_domain_model_job'
        routeFieldName: 'path_segment'
        routeValuePrefix: '/'
```

**Controller:**

```
/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function jobAction(int $id) { }
```

**Problem**

The generated URL looks fine: */de/karriere/technischen-verkaufsberaterin-aussendienst*
But when you want to access the page a `PageNotFoundException` is thrown.

Do I need to make any additional configurations or did I configure anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `routeValuePrefix`.

After I removed it, the URL could be resolved.
I assume, that this leads to a double slash when resolving: */de/karriere//technischen-verkaufsberaterin-aussendienst*